# how to change encoding of text from rss feed?

Tags: android, text, encoding, rss

A little help needed here. im sure its simple. but here my problem

I have "just about" successfully got my RSS feed displaying in my android app. Only issue is my text encoding is not right. For example the issue is:

`John's coat is Blue!, it cost £10`

In the RSS Feed in the App its displaying like so:

`John&#039; coat is Blue!, it cost &#xa3;10`

What do i have to do in order to rectify this issue. i have searched all over stack overflow and Google and found many issue relating to HTML which of course is not for me. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

My RSS feed is RSS 2.0, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
      xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
```

The code im using is found [here](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/19/android-simplified-source-code-for-parsing-and-working-with-xml-data-and-web-services-in-android/)

Ps:

-If you know how to add images into the feed please let me know here, My feed does contain images but they are not being showed in the app

-Another one is there is only 3 lines of the text feed being showed in the app if anyone know how to increase the amount of text being displayed

Sorry about all of the questions at the end!

Thanks!